# Expressing you want to become an entrepreneur down the line in interviews?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, management, career-development

How do HRs and management react if they know that you have a zeal to become an entrepreneur. In my opinion there are several advantages for the organization hiring those kind of candidates - to start with, they do not need to be motivated and will never hesitate to take an extra mile.

With that said they can also get offended or consider others with same profile who haven't express that thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do HRs and management react if they know that you have a zeal to
>   become an entrepreneur.

If by "zeal to become an entrepreneur" you basically mean "I don't really want to work for you, I want to work for myself as soon as I am able", then they would likely react negatively.

(The exception would be a job that might lead to some sort of entrepreneurship within the corporation, such as a franchised chain of locations, for example.)

Hiring managers (and the HR folks who assist them) are in the business of filling roles in their company, not helping you get your entrepreneurship off the ground. While overall "zeal" is probably a good thing, "zeal to work for myself" doesn't do much to help them. Most likely they would wonder how long you would stick around and if you would be more motivated to work on building your own business rather than excelling in theirs.

In your resume, cover letter, and during interviews, I'd suggest avoiding a discussion of a desire to be your own boss, and focus instead on why you'd be a great employee while filling the open position at hand.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the company.

Some companies have a culture where internal entrepreneurialism is valued, and would be thrilled to find a candidate who was looking to learn and practice that sort of risk taking.

Some companies will view that as "I'm going to leave in a few years, and may be distracted by my personal projects".

Some companies will view that as "I'm hard to manage" (since I want to be my own boss).

It's hard to say without knowing what companies you're applying to and how you talk about the subject.

Comment: I had experiences in all of the above. Very few companies would want you to take ownership like treating their customers as your customer etc. What I have experienced is that most companies want to get the pros of an entrepreneurial mindset (eg: passion, engagement) and leave out the cons (hard to manage, independent)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think the bigger issue is that "want to become an entrepreneur someday" is trying to get them to hire on you on things you haven't done for credentials you don't have.

An architect doesn't get hired for wanting to put a building on the New York skyline. A mathematician doesn't get hired for thinking about proving the Riemann hypothesis some day.

So: negatively, because you're talking about qualities you *don't* have, not qualities you do have.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the context of how you mention this. What sort of question do you anticipate being asked where you would answer it with what you said?

Me personally I would not recommend telling a potential employer that you're planning to leave, even though it is for "noble" reasons.

However, it is difficult to gauge how one might take this in. A professional tip is that if you are in doubt, simply go with your guts. Is your gut telling you that it would be viewed badly? Then it probably will be.